# How to apply tf.layers.add on different models' weights?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I am trying to make an **element-wise addition** on the weights of two different models.

I developed the following algorithm :

```
async function getWeights(url){
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
  const model  =  await tf.loadLayersModel(url);
  resolve(model.layers[0].getWeights);
});
}

async function aggregate(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    weights.push(getWeights('file://./mymodel/modelReceived.json'));
    weights.push(getWeights('file://./mymodel/model.json'));
    let averageLayer = tf.layers.average();
    console.log(weights.length);
    const average = averageLayer.apply([weights[0], weights[1]]);
    model.layers[0].setWeights[average];
    resolve(model);
  });

}

async function returnValue(){
  var model = await aggregate();
  console.log(model);
}

returnValue();
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
(node:20468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: A merge layer should be called on an Array of at least 2 inputs. Got 1 input(s).
```

I created the models with the following code:

```
const modelOne = tf.sequential();
modelOne.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 100, activation: 'relu', inputShape: [50]}));
modelOne.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError', metrics: ['accuracy']});
```

Can anyone explain the error to me? Are there any alternative ways to make the addition?

Answer (score 0):

the function `getWeights()` returns a Promise so when you call `weights.push(getWeights('...'))` you are passing in a Promise instead of a Tensor. it can be updated like so:

```
weights.push(await getWeights('...'))
```

the Promise in `getWeights()` resolves to a Function (i.e. `model.layers[0].getWeights`) instead of resolving to the weights:

```
resolve(model.layers[0].getWeights())
```

you should not need to do both Promise and async/await. you can simplify the `getWeights()` function like so:

```js
async function getWeights(url){
  const model  =  await tf.loadLayersModel(url);
  return model.layers[0].getWeights();
}
```

the `aggregate()` can also use similar updates.

you can find more detail on Promises & async/await here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323